# groupByKey vs hashPartitioner and mapPartitions?

Tags: apache-spark

So, I have a data like the following,

```
[ (1, data1), (1, data2), (2, data3), (1, data4), (2, data5) ]
```

which I want to convert to the following, for further processing.

```
[ (1, [data1, data2, data4]), (2, [data3, data5]) ]
```

One way is to use `groupByKey`. Another way, is to partition the RDD according to the key using `hashPartitioner`, and then process the values for each key using `mapPartitions`. Which method would be more efficient?

Comment: You should use `reduceByKey` instead of `groupByKey`. See http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html.

Comment: In this case I think groupByKey and the partition method will be equally efficient, as the shuffle that will have to be done is exactly the same (put all the same keys in the same partition), with the difference that in this case the output of groupByKey is exactly what you expect, while in the other case you will have to go with mapPartitions...

In any case, I would go with reduceByKey as suggested by jarandaf mapping first the object to lists as mattinbits points in his answer.

Comment: I actually went with mapPartitions. I see its much faster than the groupByKey method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `reduceByKey` directly as recommended in the comments, but if you map the `(Int, Object)` pairs to `(Int, List(Object))` then you can use it. I would expect the following to be among the most efficient methods however really practical tests are the best way to know which is best for your particular use case.

```
object main extends App {

  import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("example")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val data = List((1, "data1"), (1, "data2"), (2, "data3"), (1, "data4"), (2, "data5"))

  val rdd = sc.parallelize(data).mapValues(str => List(str)).reduceByKey((l1, l2) => l1 ::: l2)
  rdd.collect().foreach{
    case (key, list) => println(s"key: $key values: ${list.mkString(";")}")
  }
  sc.stop()
}
```